# how to use smart pointer to build a tree?

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

Assume that I have a employee tree and every employees have coworkers, coworkers have coworkers ..... I set up two class **employee** using to store employee's information and **eTree** represent the **tree** architecture.

Every employee has a **vector** stores **smart pointer** pointing to their coworkers. Look at following code. Why the address the smart pointer pointing become **00000000** finally. I've return the pointer out of function **buildChilds**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class employee
{
    std::string NAME;
    int NUM;
    int Enum = 0;
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<employee>> childs;
    employee(std::string name, int num) :NAME(name), NUM(num)
    {
        childs.resize(num);
    }
    std::string getName()
    {
        return NAME;
    }
    int getNum()
    {
        return NUM;
    }
    void setEnum(int num)
    {
        Enum = num;
    }
    int getEnum()
    {
        return Enum;
    }
};

class eTree
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<employee> proot;
public:
    eTree(employee node) { proot = std::make_shared<employee> (node); }
    void buildTree(std::shared_ptr<employee> parent);
    std::shared_ptr<employee> getP() { return proot; }
    std::shared_ptr<employee> buildChilds(employee &parent, int i);
};
void eTree::buildTree(std::shared_ptr<employee> parent)
{
    int num = parent->getNum();
    if (num != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            (*parent).childs[i] = buildChilds(*parent, i);
            std::cout << (*parent).childs[i] << std::endl;
            buildTree((*parent).childs[i]);
        }
        int eNum = (*parent).getNum();
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            eNum += (*((*parent).childs[j])).getEnum();
        }
        (*parent).setEnum(eNum);
    }
}
std::shared_ptr<employee> eTree::buildChilds(employee &parent, int i)
{
    std::string name;
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter the name of " << parent.getName() << "'s " << i + 1 << " child:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "How many employee work for " << parent.getName() << "'s " << i + 1 << " child:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num;
//  employee child(name, num);
    std::shared_ptr<employee> pchild (new employee(name, num));
//  std::shared_ptr<employee> pchild = std::make_shared<employee>(child);

    return pchild;
}

void more3(employee parent);
void noChild(employee parent);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    std::string name;
    cout << "Enter the employee's name: ";
    cin >> name;
    int num;
    cout << "How many employees work for him/her: ";
    cin >> num;
    employee root(name, num);
    shared_ptr<employee> proot = make_shared<employee> (root);
    eTree tree(root);
    tree.buildTree(proot);

    cout << tree.getP()->childs[0] << endl;
    cout << tree.getP()->childs[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You could input **a->2->b->0->c->0**, and then see the result;
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating many copies of the root employee and using the copies in different places.

In your main function, try the following:

```
shared_ptr<employee> proot = make_shared<employee> (name, num);
eTree tree(proot);
tree.buildTree(proot);
```

And then update your `eTree` constructor:

```
eTree(std::shared_ptr<employee> node) { proot = node; }
```

---

My reasoning:

In your code, it appears that you create a new employee:

```
employee root(name, num);
```

Then you make a **copy** of that but a smart pointer:

```
shared_ptr<employee> proot = make_shared<employee> (root);
```

Then you give the original to the eTree:

```
eTree tree(root);
```

and the copy to the buildTree function:

```
tree.buildTree(proot);
```

Thus, build tree builds the tree for another copy of employee

*edit:* Also your constructor for eTree makes yet another copy as a smart pointer, so in the end you end up with 3 instances of the original employee.

Remove the copy constructor of employee as follow and you will see what happens:

```
employee(const employee&) = delete;
```

My code will compile, your code will not...

---

*Edit*: Example code to show that `std::make_shared<>()` construct a new object:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "    -> MyClass Constructor called\n"; }
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) { std::cout << "    -> MyClass Copy Constructor called\n"; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "[1] Making MyClass\n";
    MyClass myClass;
    std::cout << "[2] Making MyClass Pointer\n";
    MyClass* myClassPtr = new MyClass();
    std::cout << "[3] Making MyClass Shared using New\n";
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClassSmart1 = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass());
    std::cout << "[4] Making MyClass Shared\n";
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClassSmart2 = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    std::cout << "[5] Making MyClass Shared from first MyClass\n";
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myClassSmart3 = std::make_shared<MyClass>(myClass);
    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```

The above code proves that `std::make_shared<T>()` constructs a new object instead of just creating a shared pointer for an already existing object. 
Also, `std::make_shared<Class>(class)` uses the copy constructor to create the new object.

The output of the above on my computer is:

```
[1] Making MyClass
    -> MyClass Constructor called
[2] Making MyClass Pointer
    -> MyClass Constructor called
[3] Making MyClass Shared using New
    -> MyClass Constructor called
[4] Making MyClass Shared
    -> MyClass Constructor called
[5] Making MyClass Shared from first MyClass
    -> MyClass Copy Constructor called
Done
```

Comment: I think `shared_ptr<employee> proot = make_shared<employee> (root);` just set a smart pointer to original object but not a copy. If it's a copy, your answer make sense;

Comment: `make_shared<Class>(args)` is a safe way to get the same as `shared_ptr<Class>(new Class(args))`. So it results in your case to `shared_ptr<employee> proot = shared_ptr<employee>(new employee(root));`. See the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)

Comment: I think I know what is wrong. `employee root(name, num)` ---the 1st object--- and `make_shared<employee> (node);`---the 2nd object--- build two identical objects but have different addresses. `eTree tree(root);` build a **tree** object and it's **proot** pointe to the 1st object. Then function tree.buildTree---a function actually has nothing to do with **eTree** class because it dose use any member in eTree class---just help the 2nd object to build up a tree architecture and it will be delete after the function finish its task. However in the tree class we just could access to the 1st object.

Comment: So I still feel `shared_ptr<employee> proot = make_shared<employee> (root);` just set a smart pointer to original object but not a copy;

Comment: Extract from the link provided: "This function is typically used to **replace** the **construction** `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...))` of a shared pointer from the raw pointer returned by a call to new."  Trust me, and the docs if I say that it creates a new object. If it just converted it would have stated _does not construct_

Comment: @sydridgm I have added example code to my answer that you can compile and run to show that your understanding of `make_shared<>()` is incorrect.

Comment: thanks for your example, it makes me have a new understanding about `make_shared<>()`.

Comment: @sydridgm You are welcome. Just remember to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.